# airmon-ng eth0 start: ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory

Tags: airmon-ng

I get this error when running `airmon-ng` on my Oracle VM. Not really sure why it's happening I'm fully updated and upgraded. When I try to run the command `airmon-ng eth0 start` it just gives me that message. Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you see, eth0 is an "cable" interface, generally speaking. You have to follow a procedure, which looks like that:

```
airmon-ng       ### Shows the available wireless interfaces.
 
airmon-ng start wlan0  ### Start a monitoring interface, usually named mon0     
 
airodump-ng mon0    ### Just observing the available wireless networks
```

Answer (score 0):

- go to http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/
- download the file "compat-wireless-2010-10-26-p.tar.bz2"
- now extract it with "tar -jxvf compat-wireless-2010-10-26-p.tar.bz2"
- go inside the folder with "cd (name of folder)"
- type "make unload"
- type "make load"
- Problem Solved ! :)